# Vscode Window stucked when remote desk to windows system and open second vscode to edit something

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, freeze

Working environment:
Operating system: windows 10 10.0.19045.2604 x64 simplified Chinese version
VS Code version: update to the latest

Steps where the problem arises:

1. Use this computer normally (assuming it is called A) to open the first VS Code window for normal coding
2. Wait for a while(maybe half a day or a day?)
3. Use another computer (let’s call it B) to remote computer A, the remote tool used here is mstsc.exe
4. Continue to use computer B to remote computer A, and open the second VS Code window. At this time, when editing files, searching content, creating new files, etc., as long as you press the keyboard, the window will be stuck. The VS Code window had to be minimized then maximized to get back to normal, but none of the keyboard input worked.

Temporary workaround:
Continue to operate on the remote computer,

1. Close all VS Code windows
2. Reopen the VS Code window
3. On the remote computer, VS Code can be used normally for editing.

What I expect from an answer post: Solve the problem that the window of VS Code using the keyboard is stuck when the windows is connected remotely.
Don't rely on the anti-human design of closing all VS Code windows to solve this problem.